# use image with flowplayer

Tags: html, flowplayer

I'm sure this is basic stuff but I'm obviously missing something.  I want to use an image with flowplayer like:

```
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv" id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px">
<img src="recordings/flow_eye.jpg" /></a>
```

I generate an html table from a database which has a list of all the videos and some other data.  I want to put the image and table beside each other and when someone clicks on a video in the table the video will start where the image currently resides.

I guess I'm confused on how to separate the img from the video link.

Comment: Move it outside of the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the image in a div with an id.  That gives me more flexibility.